# Как убрать класс ошибки с поля при его заполнении?

Tags: jquery

Делаю валидацию формы, очень примитивно:

```
    $("#order_form button").click(function(event) {

        event.preventDefault();

        if ($("input[name='name']").val() == "") {
            $("input[name='name']").addClass("error");
        }

        if ($("input[name='phone']").val() == "") {
            $("input[name='phone']").addClass("error");
        }

        if ($("input[name='email']").val() != "") {
            var pattern = /^([a-z0-9_\.-])+@[a-z0-9-]+\.([a-z]{2,4}\.)?[a-z]{2,4}$/i;
            if (!pattern.test($("input[name='email']").val())) {
                $("input[name='email']").addClass("error");
            }
        }
        else {
            $("input[name='email']").addClass("error");
        }

        if ($("select[name='payment_system']").val() == "0") {
            $(".jq-selectbox__select").addClass("error");
        }

    });
```

Если нажать кнопку отправки при пустых полях, то полям добавляется класс .error. Как сделать удаление класса .errow на лету, без повторного нажатия кнопки отправки, если поле заполнено?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Данный код Вам поможет:

```
$(document).on('input change', '#order_form input', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('error');
});
```

Вместо input можете уточнить селектор.